# How to append entire row using for loop for pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, data-cleaning

I wanted to append the entire row based on a if statement condition using for loop. My for loop only appended a specific column instead of appending them all.

i tried giving append two parameters, but it didn't work since it only accepts one parameter.

```py
android_clean = [] #lsit of new cleaned data
already_added = [] #list of the cleaned app names

for idx, row in android_data.iterrows():
    name  = row['App']
    n_reviews = float(row['Reviews'])

    if(reviews_max[name] == n_reviews)and (name not in already_added):
        android_clean.append(name)
        already_added.append(name) #make sure this inside the if block

len(android_clean)
```

a row contains 7 to 8 different columns. my code only appends the app name. I need to append the entire row including all of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Append the row and not the row['App']. 
The row is the whole row in itterrows().

```
android_clean = [] #lsit of new cleaned data
already_added = [] #list of the cleaned app names

for idx, row in android_data.iterrows():
    name  = row['App']
    n_reviews = float(row['Reviews'])

    if(reviews_max[name] == n_reviews)and (name not in already_added):
        android_clean.append(row)
        already_added.append(name) #make sure this inside the if block

len(android_clean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android_clean.append(name)` by `android_clean.append(row)`.

**Without for loop**: I would suggest you to not use `iterrows` and prefer built-in functions of Pandas that would be more efficient to perform computation.

I assumed that `reviews_max` is a dictionary in your code because you used name as keys. Here is a two line code that should give you the same result as your for loop.

```
max_reviews = android_data['App'].replace(reviews_max)
android_clean = android_data.loc[row['Reviews'].astype('float') == max_reviews]\
                            .drop_duplicates("App")
```